# Jackson deserialization circumventing final fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, immutability, lombok

Here's the code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Fields f1 = new Fields(1);
        System.out.println(f1);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(f1);
        System.out.println(str);

        Fields f2 = mapper.readValue(str, Fields.class);
        System.out.println(f2);
    }

    @Data
    @ToString
    public static class Fields {
        private final long value1;
        private final long value2;

        public Fields(@JsonProperty("blah") long value) {
            this.value1 = value++;
            this.value2 = value++;
            System.out.println(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Main.Fields(value1=1, value2=2)
Main.Fields(value1=1, value2=2)
{"value1":1,"value2":2}
Main.Fields(value1=0, value2=1)
Main.Fields(value1=1, value2=2)
```

My questions are:

- Why did jackson modify private final fields that do not have setters after finish constructing it? If this is intended, how do I turn it off?
- If jackson is able to set fields directly, why is it required that I annotate the constructor with @JsonProperty? (Removing @JsonProperty from Fields results in error; and I didn't even need to annotate with correct properties)

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why is it required that I annotate the constructor with @JsonProperty?

It's not. What is required is an accessible constructor. You can either have a parameterless constructor

```
public Fields() {
    this.value1 = 0;
    this.value2 = 0;
    System.out.println("cons: " + this);
}
```

(that necessarily initializes the fields since they are `final`) or you can have a constructor that Jackson will try to resolve based on the declared `@JsonProperty` name. Note that `JsonProperty#required` is `false` by default.

> Why did jackson modify private final fields that do not have setters
>   after finish constructing it? If this is intended, how do I turn it
>   off?

Because it can. It thus allows you to use immutable types with deserialization. There is no built-in way that I know of through which you can disable this feature.

Comment: "Because it can." - This made me smile.

Comment: But how, or with what underlying mechanism, does ObjectMapper modify the final fields? I know it uses reflection, but does it somehow make the field non-final and set it?

Comment: Surely though, if an annotated constructor exists then Jackson shouldn't be modifying fields? It should be one or the other.

Comment: @mjaggard I can't verify this at the moment, but I assume Jackson tries to assign each property in the JSON, whether through the constructor or through mutators (setters or fields).

Answer (score 17):

> Why did jackson modify private final fields that do not have setters after finish constructing it? If this is intended, how do I turn it off?

You can set `MapperFeature.ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS` property to `false` (it is `true` by default) when configuring your mapper.

Example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Temp {

    private static final String RAW = "{\"value1\": \"aabbcc\",\"value2\":\"zzzzz\"}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue(RAW, TestClass.class));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); // you will receive UnrecognizedPropertyException without this line
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS, false);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(RAW, TestClass.class));
    }

    public static class TestClass {

        private final String value1;
        private final String value2;

        @JsonCreator
        public static TestClass createTestClass(
                @JsonProperty("value1") String value1,
                @JsonProperty("blah") String value2) {

            return new TestClass(value1, value2);
        }

        private TestClass(String value1, String value2) {
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

        public String getValue1() {
            return value1;
        }

        public String getValue2() {
            return value2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TestClass{" + "value1=" + value1 + ", value2=" + value2 + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TestClass{value1=aabbcc, value2=zzzzz}
TestClass{value1=aabbcc, value2=null}
```